# Windows 10 - Task bar not always on top

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm running `Windows 10 [Version 10.0.17763.379]` and I have a strange problem.

On my primary display, windows seem to always want to be in front of the Task Bar. But on my secondary, they go behind it. I would really love it if they always went behind it so that I could always access the task bar.

Here is what it looks like between my two monitors

[image: A screen shot of the middle of my two monitors.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the taskbar is locked. Open the taskbar settings, unlock them and change the position of the taskbar on the screen before restoring it. Then check to see if the problem can be solved.

If the problem persists, please create a new local administrator account and check if the problem exists in the newly created account.

Or there is a powershell command for you:

```
$manifest = (Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.WindowsStore).InstallLocation + '\AppxManifest.xml' ; Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $manifest

Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers |Where-Object {$_.InstallLocation -like "*SystemApps*"}
```

Then restart your PC and it should be fixed.

Comment: I have been using StackExchange for something close to 10 years, and never have i been more grateful that an answer has solved my problem. This is been plaguing me for over a year now. From the bottom of my heart, sir, thank you.